# Why I get socket hang up on Postman and 502 in nginX while Gin-Gonic has returned StatusOk on both scenarios?

Tags: go, timeout, go-gin

Just to simplify my question I have a long running route that could take up to 2 minutes to return response. Now this is my sample http handler:

```
func GetHealth(svc *service.Hotel) gin.HandlerFunc {
   return func(c *gin.Context) {
      time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
      c.JSON(200, gin.H{})
   }
}
```

Now when I call `[GET] /health` route postman returns `Error: socket hang up` at the exact time of returning response from gin-gonic which is logged `200 Ok`:

`[GIN] 2024/01/24 - 11:10:58 | 200 | 30.084587215s |             ::1 | GET      "/health"`

Now the same project that goes as a reverse proxy behind nginX, I get 502 nginX error on API response while my service has logged `200 Ok` .

**The question is** why I get error on client side while gin-gonic has successfully returned a response? How should I solve this problem?

[image]

I used `github.com/gin-contrib/timeout` library as I thought it is related to timeout of the route, but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `gin-gonic` you can set `WriteTimeout` on your `http.Server` in order to prevent `socket hang up` or nginx 502.

The interesting part is that it always logs 200 even if timeout exceeds, but client gets the error:

```
srv := &http.Server{
        Addr: ":9000",
        // Good practice to set timeouts to avoid Slowloris attacks.
        WriteTimeout: time.Second * 120, // THIS TIMEOUT NEEDS TO BE SET
        ReadTimeout:  time.Second * 15,
        IdleTimeout:  time.Second * 60,
        Handler:      router,
    }
```